# How to send entire logs to jeager span in Quarkus?

Tags: quarkus

Is there any way to put the std logs provided by the application and the errors to a span?
I wanted to put slf4j logs provided in quarkus and it should show up in jeager-Ui

[Quarkus log information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulEmJ.png)

**application.properties**

```
quarkus.http.port=8200
quarkus.swagger-ui.always-include=true
quarkus.jaeger.service-name=myservice
quarkus.jaeger.reporter-log-spans=true
quarkus.jaeger.log-trace-context=true
quarkus.jaeger.propagation=jaeger
quarkus.jaeger.sampler-type=const
quarkus.jaeger.sampler-param=1
quarkus.log.console.format=%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p traceId=%X{traceId}, spanId=%X{spanId}, sampled=%X{sampled} [%c{2.}] (%t) %s%e%n

quarkus.log.handler.gelf.enabled=true
quarkus.log.handler.gelf.host=localhost
quarkus.log.handler.gelf.port=12201
```

Below are dependencies which I am using to achieve centralized log management(ELK).For that I am using guides provided by quarkus [quarkus-centralized-log-managemt guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/centralized-log-management)

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-opentracing</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-logging-gelf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-metrics</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: Well, I don't think that shipping logs  into Jaeger would be a good idea. The main purpose of Jaeger is Traceability and Observability and it should be very lightweight to avoid a performance degradation. A nice alternative would be printing Jaeger trace id and span id in your logs (Usually they are also aggregated into some centralised log stack like EFK) and filter your logs with trace id or span id.

Comment: Thanks for providing me a nice alternative. But I wanted to know whether there is any way in quarkus to get preHandle & afterCompletion events with info about the class / method that were called during request execution like we have in springboot

Comment: I think you could find an answer about this around CDI interceptors(https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/interceptors.html). It is also supported by Quarkus. simple example (https://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/simple-cdi-interceptor/).

Comment: I had implemented the alternative you suggested i.e by printing traceId and spanId in my logs and I tried to configure jeager with elasticsearch on windows server without using docker by searching all options available with zero success.I think somehow I had gone in a wrong way.Can you please provide me some help me here?

Comment: Firstly, are using elastic search alone or it is with some kind of stack like EFK(Elastic/Fluentd & Kibana) ? secondly, what do you mean by "searching all options available with zero success ?" If traceId and spanId are in logs you should be able to filter them.

Comment: I am using ELK(Elastic/Logstash & Kibana).I have been successful in sending Jeager data to ELK.I am attaching a screenshot for description.First log which you are seeing in above link(Quarkus log information(image)) is configured through slf4j which is not showing up in Kibana.I am new to these concepts.So,Please correct me if am going in a wrong way and excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Just one inquiry, You are mentioning that you are successfully able to send data to ELK and then you are mentioning that it is not showing on Kibana, which statement is true ?

Comment: Sorry for creating confusion.If I create logs by using (span.log("....")) those are showing up but not slf4j logs.

Comment: This will not be configured automatically, you need to add some configuration in your application.properties. I will post it in the answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had added a new gelf configuration property in my application.properties.By this we can send logs with traceId and spanId to ELK stack.

*application.properties*

```
quarkus.http.port=8200
quarkus.swagger-ui.always-include=true
quarkus.jaeger.service-name=myservice
quarkus.jaeger.reporter-log-spans=true //This can be excluded
quarkus.jaeger.propagation=jaeger //This can be excluded
quarkus.jaeger.sampler-type=const
quarkus.jaeger.sampler-param=1
quarkus.log.console.format=%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p traceId=%X{traceId}, spanId=%X{spanId}, sampled=%X{sampled} [%c{2.}] (%t) %s%e%n

quarkus.log.handler.gelf.enabled=true
quarkus.log.handler.gelf.host=localhost
quarkus.log.handler.gelf.port=12201
quarkus.log.handler.gelf.include-full-mdc=true //newly added property
```

Answer (score 0):

You can @Inject Tracer and add your own stuff in it.

But I thought that errors would be automatically logged in Jaeger, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, errors would get automatically logged in Jeager but I wanted to know at what conditions we need to create spans and use span.log() because I am new to Open tracing and Jeager

Answer (score 0):

After configuring your logs to accept Jaeger attributes like for ex :

> quarkus.log.console.format=%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c{2.}] (%t)
> [traceId=%X{traceId},spanId=%X{spanId},%X{sampled}] %s%e%n

Then you need to propagate Jaeger context to your logs through the below properties :

> quarkus.jaeger.log-trace-context=true
>
> quarkus.jaeger.propagation=jaeger

Comment: I forgot to mention you that I am using quarkus-logging-gelf extension and done configurations based on same as mentioned in [quarkus-centralized-log-management-guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/centralized-log-management) to send logs to ELK.By using above configurations you mentioned in the answer I had tried but traceId and spanId are not getting sent.

Comment: Please share your properties file and pom.xml

Comment: I will just edit my question to share properties file and pom.xml

Comment: Are you configuring property "quarkus.jaeger.endpoint" correctly ?!

Comment: Yes I had configured property like quarkus.jaeger.endpoint=http://localhost:14268/api/traces

Comment: It should start with http:// or https:// I believe.

Comment: Hey,Thanks for your time.The issue got resolved I just added an configuration in application.properties related to quarkus-logging-gelf

Comment: Glad to hear this! Please update my answer with your finding and mark it as solved. So other people can reference it in future.

Comment: Please add the new configuration that you've configured in the answer or tell me what you did to update it.

Comment: I had posted the new configuration in the answer section.